# Add Data Annotation on Business Object outside of the WEB project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Here is my application architecture:

Data Access Layer
BusinessEntities
Businesslayer
WEB

In the web project, When one user want to see one object:

Web request the Businesslayer, Businesslayer request the DAL, DAL request DB and put data into BusinessEntities, so BusinessEntities Object is retrieved in the WEB project.

Now I Want to add Data Annotations to use DisplayNameFor method on the View but adding data annotation looks like unpossible in the BusinessEntities, I can't add the usingSystem.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; in top of BusinessEntities.

Can I make something like partial class (I think that no because of the namespace) or anything else to add Data Annotations ?

In the DAL I use ADO.NET.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow,

> Web request the Businesslayer, Businesslayer request the DAL, DAL
>   request DB and put data into BusinessEntities, so BusinessEntities
>   Object is retrieved in the WEB project.

you need to introduce ViewModel. BusinessEntities will be transformed into ViewModel and ViewModel is what you should send to or get from view. Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) tool to do most of transformation.

You can apply DataAnnotations on ViewModel.

Follow up question are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your ask. I already use ViewModel but not for the simple retrieval of data's...

Comment: Ok that's good, it might make sense to add a scenario with some code to explain what you are trying to achieve. Just a suggestion.